# Sweet Alert http request with Angular doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sweetalert

I'm creating a form with Sweet Alert and I have a post request inside the swal function but when I hit submit nothing happens. Would appreciate some help.

```
$scope.formModal = function(){
swal({background:'#ACF1F4',html:"<form method='post' id='loginform'>Username:
<input id='username' name='username' >
<br><br>Password:<input type='password' id='password' name='password'><br>  <br></form>",
confirmButtonText: 'Submit',showCancelButton: true}
, function(){
$http.post("login.php",{"username":username,"password":password})
.success(function(data){swal(data)})
}
);

}
```

Comment: Can you post the result of `console.log(data);`?

Comment: I moved the ajax call outside the swal function by saying ".then()" Now I'm getting data but it's all a bunch of errors. Is there some issue with defining the password and username inputs inside swal and then sending them in the post request?

Comment: Nevermind. I got it to work. I stored the form inputs in variables inside the .then() function and then passed them to the http call.

Comment: Good work Aaron :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues here:

1. You cannot break a string in multiple lines the way you did.
2. You're missing a ')' in the end of your `swal` call
3. You're missing the `title` parameter, which is mandatory for `swal`
4. The HTML must receive a boolean indicating that your message contains HTML code

I'm not very sure if you can create a form inside the SweetAlert, at least there are not examples in their page.

```
swal({background:'#ACF1F4', html:true, title:"<form method='post' id='loginform'>Username: <input id='username' name='username' style='width: 100%' ><br><br>Password:<input type='password' id='password' name='password'><br>  <br></form>",
confirmButtonText: 'Submit',showCancelButton: true})
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm using Sweet Alert 2. You don't have to have the HTML boolean with that and I don't think the title is mandatory. And I only broke the string for sake of readability on this site.

Comment: The following code worked for me using SweetAlert 2

    swal({background:'#ACF1F4',html:"<form method='post' id='loginform'>Username:<input id='username' name='username' ><br><br>Password:<input type='password' id='password' name='password'><br>  <br></form>",
    confirmButtonText: 'Submit',showCancelButton: true})

I just added the missing ')' to the swal call. Also, notice you have a double comma in showCancelButton: true},, function(){

If there are still errors, please check your browser's console pressing F12.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still having trouble with the http call. Please see my response to Hackerman in the top post.